# How to handle the long string in the BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to perform concatenation for multiple columns around 23 columns and put them in one column. This is the requirement and this is how the data will be ingested by the another platform. Can you please help with how to handle the long string. As of now, the column returns no value, it is blank. I tried to do data type casting also, but it seems that google BigQuery doesn't support Clob objects.

Code is here:

```
SELECT 

cast(concat(concat('hem:sha256:',TO_HEX(SHA256(LOWER(Email_Address))),"^", 'Name__Prefix_:', Name__Prefix_,";", 
'Name__First_:', Name__First_,';', 'Name__Middle_:',Name__Middle_,';’,’Name__Last_:',Name__Last_,';','Name__Suffix_:',Name__Suffix_,';', 'Age:',Age,';', 'Phone:',Phone,';', 'Zip_Code:',Zip_Code,';', 'information:',information,';', 'updates:',updates,';', 'Eligibility_and_distribution_information:',Eligibility_and_distribution_information,';', 'Stories_from_people_who_have_been_vaccinated:',Stories_from_people_who_have_been_vaccinated,';', 'Created_By__User_Id_:',Created_By__User_Id_,';', 'Entry_Id:',Entry_Id,';', 'Entry_Date:',Entry_Date,';', 'Source_Url:',Source_Url,';'),
concat('Payment_Date:',Payment_Date,';', 'Payment_Status:',Payment_Status,';', 'Post_Id:',Post_Id,';', 'User_Agent:',User_Agent,';', 'User_IP:',User_IP)) as clob)
FROM `TableName`;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not %100 clear on the question but let me try.
There is no `CLOB` type in BigQuery, but `string` type should be enough for most cases. *(as of today max row size is ~100mb)*

ps; be careful while using `concat` function with `nullable` fields, any null value in a row yield `null` result in your case.

and if you have a chance to change methods on target platform, please consider using strongly typed formats like `parquet, avro, json` and [BQ export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq) job.